# ListView not showing last item

Tags: android, listview

I've looked around already and checked out a couple answers, however some of them don't fit my scenario. I have relatively little screen space. Because of this, I don't want to use

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

This works, but like I said I don't have much space. Is there any other way of fixing the issue with the last item of the listview not completely display/displaying at all? I also need all my items on the screen to be flush so that, for example, 4 row items fit exactly into the listview, which means you can't see any additional rows on that screen until scrolling.

EDIT:

This is my list view

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/infoList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    />
```

This is my xml for my items that are added to the listview

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/info_view_item_nodesc_constraint_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/infoName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/poi_list_entry_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/infoIcon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also I have a ActionMenuView on the bottom of my screen, which is the same size as the action bar up top.

Comment: It's difficult answering without the XML of your layouts

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to recycler view